# Need to fetch data into array BEFORE sending it as a prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rbac

I am fetching the user's permissions from an API call. I get the permissions and push them to an array that will be sent as a prop to another component. The fetch_permissions function returns exactly what I need, yet it doesn't seem to be waiting for the function to complete before sending incomplete data. Here is my code:

```js
// src/components/NavBar.js

import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "../react-auth0-spa";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import AccessControl from './accessControl';

const NavBar = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout, getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const userPermissions =[];
  
 

  //fetch permissions
  async function fetch_permissions(){
    try {
      const token = await getTokenSilently();
      const response = await fetch("/permissions", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });

      const permissions = await response.json();
      console.log(permissions);
      for (let i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
        let permission = permissions[i];
        userPermissions.push(permission);
      }
      console.log(userPermissions);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  fetch_permissions();
  return (
    <div>
        {/* Links to show regardless of login state */}
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>&nbsp;

        {/* Links to show when logged in */}
        {isAuthenticated && (
        <span>
          
            <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
            {console.log(userPermissions)}
            <AccessControl userPermissions={userPermissions} allowedPermissions={["admin:admin"]} protectedResource={<Link to="/administration">Admin</Link>} />
            <Link to="/external-api">External API</Link>
            <button onClick={() => logout()}>Log out</button>
        </span>
        )}
    
        {/* Show if not logged in */}
        {!isAuthenticated && (
          <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect({})}>Log in</button>
        )}

    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

I know this has something to do with javascript being asyncronous, but I can't figure out another way to accomplish this. When the page loads in the browser the console logs are out of order and the data from within the fetch_permissions is completely different than the data logged right before sending it as a prop (See attached). What do I need to do to resolve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add two hooks: `useState` and `useEffect`.

Initialize the `userPermissions` array with `useState`. Then, within `useEffect`, fetch your data and update `userPermissions` using the updater function. This will trigger a re-render and pass along the newest value to the child component.

You can find more info about this, along with handling loading and error states, here: [How to fetch data with React Hooks?](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data)

```
const [userPermissions, setUserPermissions] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchPermissions() {
    try {
      // ...
      const permissions = response.json();
      setUserPermissions(permissions);
    } catch (error) {
      // ...
    }
  }

  fetchPermissions();
}, []);
```

Comment: This eventually returns the correct data, however by the time it does it has already been passed as an empty array to the AccessControl component. Once it loads, it does not pass the populated array to the component either.

Comment: What's in your `AccessControl` component? Unless you are manually handling prop updates, it should receive the new array and re-render accordingly. Here's a basic example of `useState` and `useEffect` with an async function in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-frost-7ppgl